# iText page number references

Tags: reference, itext

I am generating a large document that will have many references to other pages in the document. For instance, the text might say:

"This topic is covered in Chapter 46 (see page XX)."

or

"See the chart on page XX"

Since I don't know the page number ahead of time, my initial thought was to create the PDF in multiple passes, as outlined in "iText in Action", chapter 6. However, as I understand it, this would not work because the PDFStamper cannot edit existing chunks of text once they are created. My second thought is to create the document twice. The first time, I would create the document and simply make a hashmap of referenced places in the text and page numbers. The second time, I would use those to generate references.

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Create a `PdfTemplate` as placeholder for all the *unknown* data, store these in an array.

Mark the referred text with `onGenericTag()` and fill out the templates stored in the array with the page number.

Main problem: how to define the size of the `PdfTemplate`? That problem can't be solved.

Comment: That solution seems extremely problematic. Would it work to actually create the document twice: the first time simply collecting an array of markers and page numbers and then throwing out that document. The second time would be creating the real document, using the array to substitute the page numbers for the uses of the markers. What do you think?

Comment: No, that wouldn't help. We're talking about PDF, not about a Word processing format. (You shouldn't confuse PDF with an editing format.)